# An error occurred while transferring data from TDengine 2.4 to TDengine 3.0 with taosdump

Tags: tdengine

taosdump.3340632973591 is from TDengine 2.4.
When I try to recover data in TDengine 3.0 ,I have a problem.

Here's the code

```
root@nofeel:~# taosdump -i taosdump.3340632973591 
taosdump: symbol lookup error: taosdump: undefined symbol: inflateReset
```

```
root@nofeel:~# tree taosdump.3340632973591 
dbs.sql                               data155559  data183342  data211125  data4443    data72213  
data127776                               data15556   data183343  data211126  data44430   data72214
data127777                               data155560  data183344  data211127  data44431   data72215
data127778                               data155561  data183345  data211128  data44432   data72216
data127779                               data155562  data183346  data211129  data44433   data72217
data12778                                data155563  data183347  data21113   data44434   data72218
data127780                               data155564  data183348  data211130  data44435   data72219
```

I try to reinstall taostool2.2.1. But the error still occurs.

```
root@nofeel:~# taosdump
taosdump: symbol lookup error: taosdump: undefined symbol: inflateReset
```

Answer (score 0):

according to https://github.com/taosdata/taos-tools/issues/367, it happened due to CDN cache issue then the package is incompletely downloaded. You can try to use a clean environment like a `docker pull ubuntu:22.04` command and install TDengine and taosTools package. If failed, you can use md5sum to get their md5 value to feedback and check with official pkg's.